# XmlPullParser - looking only for "<title>" tag, but result returned for "<media:title>" too

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to parse an rss feed using the XmlPullParser looking for the `<title>` tag, if the tag is found, then extract the text inside.
Everything works great for simple rss files, but if the rss feed contains something like this: `<media:title type="html">`, the line is processed too.

However this is not the expected result, I'm looking only for `<title>`, and for `<media:title type="html">`.

And my question is how can I modify my code to achieve this, or what am I missing here?

```
try {

        URL url = new URL("http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/feed/");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    items.add(xpp.nextText());
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    // Log.d("GREC", xpp.nextText());
                    links.add(xpp.nextText());
                }
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you can turn off namespace awareness in the [factory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29), or you can check that the namespace actually is empty via [getNamespace](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getNamespace%28%29) and [NO_NAMESPACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#NO_NAMESPACE)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. setting the namespace awareness to false, resolved my issue. However, I have another question....

How do I specify to get "title" tags inside only "item" tag. Because just at the beginning of rss feed, there's such a tag called "channel", which also contains a tag "title". However I want to skip this tag, and get only those tags inside the "item" tag?  

Is this possible to do with XmlPullParser?

Comment: @VGREC Then you need to remember which tags you've seen. In this case you can for instance set a boolean to true when you encounter a _channel_ START_TAG and to false for the END_TAG. And then you can always ignore the _title_ if the boolean is true.

Comment: lordl, thank you for suggestion. I made use of boolean tags and achieved what I was looking for.